# Why when I'm adding onClick event to my button, CSVLINK(react-csv) is not working anymore?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, export-to-csv, semantic-ui, buttonclick

I have Node.Js backend and react front-end. I have a query in the backend that returning data based on category name that I enter in an input box. 
Before I add onClick event in the button it returned the results in a CSV and download it for me. After adding onClick to the button I can see that at the backend I have a successful query but at the front-end, it's not downloading my results in a csv file. I'm using the button from Semantic UI React and CSVLINK from 'react-csv' package.

Here is my code(function that I called in onClick):

```
handleReportButton(e){

e.preventDefault();
const value = e.target.value;

fetch(`/reportOnAnswersCategory`,{
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify({
  answer: value
}),
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  })
.then(data => data.json())
.then((data) => {this.setState({report : data});})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

This is the button(I have binded the function before, and I did 'const { report } = this.state;' before return):

```
<Button onClick={this.handleReportButton}>
  <CSVLink data={report} >Download this report</CSVLink>
</Button>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `handleReport` is asynchronous, so the report data isn't ready until the fetch results come back. Whereas the `CSVLink` expects the data there already. You can use `CSVDownload` to let the link do the downloading too.

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you, I'm using this now after you have suggested but how can I prevent **CSVDownload**  from triggering on mounting the component? It triggers downloading ONLY on mounting the component!

Comment: Can you show how you've implemented the `CSVDownload`?

Comment: @Jayce444 I have tried 2 ways: 1: I have changed the '<CSVLink ....' line in button with => `<CSVDownload data={report} target="_blank" />` , this way it's triggering after call component  2: I have added this line after '.catc(...'  in handleReport => `return (<CSVDownload data={this.state.report} target="_blank" />);` this way nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

To download a file in html5 what you can do is, to set an anchor tag with download attribute,

```
<a href="/reportOnAnswersCategory" download="data.csv" id="btnExport" >Export data into Excel</a>
```

And when the user clicks the link, the download attribute appears in the save. In this case, the file will be downloaded as “data.csv”

But to pass the 'answer:value' to the api either you can change the node to accept it as a query param and change the url to `href="/reportOnAnswersCategory?answer="+{value}`, 
Or you can hide the `<a>` using css style,`display:none` and onClick of your button, do `document.getElementById("btnExport").click()`

Edit: When the download is using a **POST** request,

```
fetch(service_url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },

  }).then(response => response.blob())
    .then(response => {
  var blob=response
  var reader = new window.FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onloadend = function() {
  var base64data = reader.result;

      window.open(base64data);

  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rohith but I'm not using jquery

Comment: You dont have to implement the jquery function, you can use the <a> and download attribute with href value as the url which can be set ussing your react code

Comment: Removed the jQuery code and provided two possible solutions

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Comment: unfortunately not yet